# WorkFlow Implementation in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, workflow-foundation

I need to **implement Workflow in MVC5**. Eventhough I read article about workflow,i did not get idea how to integrate workflow and MVC5.I am very new to workflow and have very little knowledge about MVC5.

My project Flow:

1. List item
2. Display request submission form.
3. User submits the request
4. Request Moves to Approver1 Queue.
5. If Approver1 approves the request, request moves to Approver2  queue.
6. Both approver can approves and rejects the request.

can anyone send the example of:

- how to create workflow and
- how to interact with MVC and
- how to display the workflow status to user?

Comment: Workflows aren't a component you integrate somewhere. They are applications that you build yourself, or buy as a separate product. You can use MVC 5 to build a workflow application.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you want to implement a workflow architecture like Windows Workflow Foundation. And then implement an MVC application to schedule / run / monitor the execution of the workflows. Its a very large topic to cover. I would start by reviewing this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483313(v=vs.110).aspx) which details some examples of implementing workflows.